# trying to implement get the nth element of a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am very new in Prolog and trying to implement get the nth element of a list in Prolog
here is my code but it throws error

```
element_at(X,[X|_],1).
element_at(X,[_|L],K) :-
   K > 1,
   K1 is K - 1,
   element_at(X,L,K1).
```

I think that X in the second line in the right side of the code has to be replaced with some thing else but I could not think of any .

Comment: @NicholasCarey: Your indentation style is very controversial. It's OK if you put it on your code, but you put it on others'

Answer (score 5):

K is not evaluated when you test it.
You need to reverse the order

```
element_at(X,[X|_],1).
element_at(X,[_|L],K) :- element_at(X,L,K1), K is K1 + 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tail-recursive version using an accumulator. Using the accumulator, its value is instantiated already on each call so you can increment first, then do the recursion.

```
element_at(X, List, Pos) :-
    element_at(X, List, 1, Pos).
element_at(X, [X|_], Pos, Pos).
element_at(X, [_|T], Acc, Pos) :-
    Acc1 is Acc + 1,
    element_at(X, T, Acc1, Pos).
```

This works with various combinations of variables on the input, but it (as well as CapelliC's non-tail recursive version) will loop infinitely if `Pos` is ground and after a possible solution is found, such as with:

```
| ?- element_at(X, L, 3).

L = [_,_,X|_] ? ;
.... loop ....
```

So a modification to check for this case avoids that:

```
element_at(X, List, Pos) :-
    element_at(X, List, 1, Pos).
element_at(X, [X|_], Pos, Pos).
element_at(X, [_|T], Acc, Pos) :-
    (nonvar(Pos) -> Acc < Pos ; true),  % fail if Acc hits ground Pos
    Acc1 is Acc + 1,
    element_at(X, T, Acc1, Pos).
```

Now you get:

```
| ?- element_at(X, L, 3).
L = [_,_,X|_] ? ;
no.
```

And:

```
| ?- element_at(X, L, P).
L = [X|_]
P = 1 ? ;
L = [_,X|_]
P = 2 ? ;
L = [_,_,X|_]
P = 3 ? ;
L = [_,_,_,X|_]
P = 4 ? ;
...etc...
```

Comment: sorry if I didn't amuse you with that comment btw; I thought I was being amusing. :$

Comment: @WillNess no worries. It was amusing. It is a little hard to tell intent in comments. But I was starting to have second thoughts about my post, especially after you had a succinct answer. The Prolog crowd on SO is a tough crowd, so I wasn't sure. ;)

Comment: not me, I hope. Never my intention, at least. :) They (we...) don't upvote as mush as I'd like sometimes, true; but they have a long way to go to what comp.lang.lisp once was (maybe still is, I wouldn't know). :)

Comment: @WillNess oh... I've been around some of the `comp.lang` groups. They can get... interesting. :)